# How to restrict features that users can see by area?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, security

Basically I have around 10 tables that are worked by several teams of users. What I need to avoid is team A complaining that team B got a better area to work on or worse, having them sabotaging each other

To delineate these areas, I have a polygon layer. Ideally, users would only see features in all tables that fall inside this polygon's area and anything outside would not be shown to them

What is the best way of achieving this? layer level security? bounding boxes tied to logins? creating views for each table for each team?

Comment: Views I guess. Because you can't see or fiddle with what you can't access.

Answer (score 2):

[Row level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) policies are basically made for situations like these, and have the advantage that they automatically permit things like `INSERTS` of data that would actually fall outside of a users permission.

The handling (and performance) of *Views* in your case should, however, be slightly better:

- add an array of user identifiers to each AOI polygon which are supposed to have access to the features covered by its area.
- `REVOKE` access to the base tables (so that users can't even see them), and have a *View* in place for each, e.g.

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW <base_table_view> AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   <base_table> AS t
    WHERE  EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   <polygon_fences> AS aoi
      WHERE  t.geom && aoi.geom
        AND  session_user = ANY(aoi.users)
    )
  );
  ```

  on which you `GRANT` the necessary permissions per user.

  The `EXISTS` construct is necessary to keep the *View* updateable; if that's too slow, you'd have to add `INSTEAD OF` triggers on *View*s with e.g. `JOIN` expressions; these would also allow you much more control of the data that gets edited (e.g. an `INSERT` restriction).